Mechanism used to automatically turn on headlights?
2010 Silverado 1500
When the headlights are in AUTO mode, the headlights automatically turn on when it’s dark at night.
What mechanism is used to sense the light level to turn on the headlights? Where is the sensor located?

On your Silverado, the sensor is in the dash, about mid way. It's a little dark colored "dome" about 1/2" in diameter. Here's where it's at on a 2006 Silverado. Your 2010 should be near the same and look the same.

